# Grep in a for loop in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, grep

I have a file containing a certain number of occurrences of a determined string called "Thermochemistry". Im trying to write a script to grep 500 lines above each occurrence of this string and create a new file numbered accordingly. What I've tried this

```
occurrences="$(grep -c 'Thermochemistry' $FILE)"

for  (( i=1; i<=$occurrences; i++)); do

        grep -B500 -m "$i" 'Thermochemistry' $FILE > newfile_"$i".tmp
done
```

If there are 20 occurrences of 'Thermochemistry' in the file, I wanted it to create 20 new files, called `newfile_1.tmp` to `newfile_20.tmp`, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: `-m $i` doesn't give you the *i*-th occurrence exclusivley, but it stops after the *i*-th occurrence.

Comment: `grep -F -B500 'Thermochemistry' file | csplit --supress-matched - '/^--$/' '{*}'`?

Comment: @oguzismail : Highly interesting comment. Maybe you can make it an answer, and explain about the `--supress-matched`.  My `csplit` for instance (Coreutils 8.26) does not have this option.

Comment: @user1934428 it's `--suppress-matched` (available in 8.31), I mistyped and apparently nobody noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next to the [magic command from oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62164092/grep-in-a-for-loop-in-linux#comment109944933_62164092), you could use the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) line:

```
awk '/Thermochemistry/{close(f);f="newfile_"++i".tmp"
          for(i=FNR;i<=FNR+(FNR>500?500:FNR);++i) print b[i%500] > f
     }{b[FNR%500]=$0}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you explain the steps you mentioned?